# Cant install Tensorflow due to protobuf issue?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am not to sure why I am getting this issue all of a sudden when trying to import tensorflow into my jupyter notebooks. The issue is related to the protobuf, and I am not to sure what happened all of a sudden that causes this error.

I did install WSL on my system yesterday and thought that might be the problem. I have subsequently uninstalled it.

Here is so the code
!pip install tensorflow
!pip install protobuf

from tensorflow.keras import models, layers
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

And it produces an error:

TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly.
If this call came from a _pb2.py file, your generated code is out of date and must be regenerated with protoc >= 3.19.0.
If you cannot immediately regenerate your protos, some other possible workarounds are:

1. Downgrade the protobuf package to 3.20.x or lower.
2. Set PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python (but this will use pure-Python parsing and will be much slower).

How do I sort this issue out?

I have tried to install a version of protobuf==3.19.5 but that still doesnt work. I am just baffled by what causes this ?

Comment: Here are some of the installed packages.

protobuf==3.19.4
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
requests==2.28.2
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
rsa==4.9
six==1.16.0
tensorboard==2.11.2
tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1
tensorflow==2.11.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.11.0
tensorflow-intel==2.11.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.30.0
tensorflow-protobuf==2.11.0

Comment: Hi @Tayla Corney, Could you please let us know which Windows OS, TensorFlow and python version you are using to help you fix this error. Please have a look at [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) for your reference if you are trying to use TensorFlow in windows WSL2.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with protobuf version mismatch with some of the Tensorflow modules.

To resolve this error, please try installing the `protobuf==3.20` after installing all the required packages and restart the kernel.

```
pip install protobuf==3.20
```